How Can I Configure Mac OS Packet Filer (pf.conf) to Reroute trafic From 1 Port to another while allowing both ports to communicate?
I'm trying to configure my macs (Monterey) packet filter rules to reroute traffic headed to port 8090 (php ratchet server) to go to port 8091 (php socket server). From there the socket server (8091) should be able to bi-communicate with the ratchet server as well as the user. currently i've tried this:
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"

# Translation (NAT)
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 8090 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8091
rdr on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 8090 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8091

# Filtering
anchor "com.apple/*"

load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
This works to an extent where the traffic headed to port 8090 reroutes to 8091 but when i try too have 8091 ccommunicate with 8090 it ends up loooping.
i've also tried:
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"

# Translation (NAT)
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"

# NAT and Redirection rules
# Redirect traffic from port 8090 to port 8091, excluding traffic from port 8091
rdr on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 8090 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8091
# Allow traffic from the proxy to the original server without redirection
pass out quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 8090 to any port 8091 keep state
pass in quick on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 port 8090 to any port 8091 keep state


# Filtering
anchor "com.apple/*"

load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
and plenty more.
